# How to Change Keys To Save a Multidimensional Array into DB using a Loop?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a form with many rows of data where each row has data of all the same type. So, each row has "ID", "Name", "Notes", "Status"

So my form looks like this. Even if you don't know Laravel, it is pretty obvious what is happening:

```
 <td>{!!Form::text("cat_id[$category->category_id]", $category->category_id) !!}</td>
 <td>{!! Form::text("cat_name[$category->category_id]",$category->name)!!}</td>
 <td>{!! Form::textarea("notes[$category->category_id]",$category->notes)!!}</td>
 <td>{!! Form::select("status[$category->category_id]", ['active'=>'Active' ,'deactivate' => 'Deactivate', 'delete' => 'Delete'],$category->status)!!}</td>
```

The POST data which comes off the form is not very usable, looks like this:

```
array:5 [▼
"_token" => "XRuGUnf6xt7m4jlrjVa4tI954XLyIcLcqfy0NGr0"
"cat_id" => array:4 [▼
42 => "42"
22 => "22"
1 => "1"
31 => "31"
]
"cat_name" => array:4 [▼
42 => "Cedar"
22 => "Materials"
1 => "Products"
31 => "Slate"
]
"notes" => array:4 [▶]
"status" => array:4 [▶]
]
```

So using array_map, I have reformatted the data to look like the below. I have two problems:

I have no idea how to change the all the keys to the correct label across all of the sub arrays.ie "ID", "Name" "Notes", "Status".

In order to save the data I **assume** I need to loop through each sub array and identify the value by a specific key which the DB understands ie "ID", "Name" "Notes" etc. I'm also struggeling to know the best way of getting that done.   Many Thanks !

```
array:4 [▼
0 => array:4 [▼
  0 => "42"
  1 => "Cedar"
  2 => "Notes"
  3 => "active"
  ]
1 => array:4 [▼
  0 => "22"
  1 => "Asphalt"
  2 => "Notes"
  3 => "active"
  ]
2 => array:4 [▶]
3 => array:4 [▶]
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're making life very difficult for yourself with how you've defined your form fields. Change your form fields so that your data is posted in a better format.

```
<td>{!! Form::text("category[$category->category_id]['category_id']", $category->category_id) !!}</td>
<td>{!! Form::text("category[$category->category_id]['name']", $category->name) !!}</td>
<td>{!! Form::textarea("category[$category->category_id]['notes']", $category->notes)!!}</td>
<td>{!! Form::select("category[$category->category_id]['status']", ['active' => 'Active', 'deactivate' => 'Deactivate', 'delete' => 'Delete'], $category->status) !!}</td>
```

Your data will then be posted through in the format:

```
[
    'category' => [
        1 => [
            'category_id' => 1,
            'name'        => '...',
            'notes'       => '...',
            'status'      => '...',
        ],
        2 => [
            'category_id' => 2,
            'name'        => '...',
            'notes'       => '...',
            'status'      => '...',
        ],
        // ...
    ],
]
```

**Follow-up Question**

When you do not know the indexes of an array, instead of using a `for` loop, you can use a `foreach` loop.

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    // ...
}
```

This would work well your case, however from your original question, it looks as though you're using Laravel. Therefore because you're wanting to update existing category models, I would suggest the following instead.

```
// Find updated categories by ID and index collection by category ID
$ids = array_keys($request->category);
$categories = Category::whereIn('category_id', $ids)->get();

// Iterate through categories
$categories->each(function ($category) use ($request) {
    // Find category attributes in request POST data and update category
    $attributes = $request->category[$category->category_id];
    $category->update($attributes); 
});
```

Comment: your copy paste couples category_id with name

Comment: Good spot. Cheers.

Comment: Brilliant ! Many thanks !  In your example, the sub categories are nicely labeled in a sequential order starting with 1, then 2 etc etc. In my case, the sub arrays could start with a random number, say 42, then 35 etc. I need to be able to save each one of these sub arrays into my DB. So using a For loop will not work when parsing the array.

Can you please give me a suggestion how best to parse over the array, so I can get then into an sql update  statement. Many Thanks !

Comment: @Vince I have edited my answer to respond to your follow-up questions. Let me know if there's anything you don't understand.

Comment: Many Thanks ! How lucky for me that I should have come across someone who is an expert in Laravel Collections! However, I have a problem with the code. I am getting an error: "Call to a member function update() on null". I use Storm. When I debug $attributes, I see it is an array containing the keys, "category_id", "name", "notes", "status" with their respective values.. This might explain why $attributes is seen as "null" ?

Comment: Ah, no. I think the problem is that I wrote the code assuming `id` was your primary key, whereas it looks to be `category_id` instead. I have revised the updated code to iterate over the categories, rather than the `POST` data, thus if no categories are found, you won't get `null` errors.

Comment: It's works !!  I can see that you used Collection methods. Except for the "use" method which I have not yet found anything on. I MUST try my best to study and understand the available functions within the Collections module. A different problem but still related. Since having altered the structure of my Categories array, my array validation no longer works.  I was using "'notes.*' => 'max:20' as the filter in the Validator::make method. With all these new nested arrays, what should it now be ?  The "notes" value is contained within the 3rd level of nested array.  I can not thank you enough !

Comment: Have a look at the [validating array](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#validating-arrays) docs. You should be able to just use `'category.*.notes' => ['required', 'max:20', ...]`

Comment: You're welcome. FYI the `use` call pertains to the use of PHP anonymous functions and specifically brings the variables specified into scope for that anonymous function. In this case the variable `$request`.